# UISegmentedController switch between collectionview & tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

Got a question about to switch views in a segmented controller between collectionview and tableview. Is that even possible? And if so, how? Is the easiest way to do it by building both of them by code in a `UIViewController` or is it possible to do right from the `UICollectionViewController`? The picture below is screening the problem.. And as it is at the moment it's a `UICollectionViewController`!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two views, v1 and v2. Add both of them to your view controller. Upon value changed event of segment control, you can hide/ unhide these views. Eg when index 0 of segment control is selected, unhide v1 and hide v2. Do vice versa when index 1 is selected. This has to be done in your code. The views which are to be displayed on index 0 selected becomes subviews of v1. Similarly, views to be displayed on index 1 become subviews of v2. Depending on how complex v1 and v2 are, you can create them in the same xib as your view controller or a different one.

Comment: Sorry for late answer.. Looks like it should be the way to do it. Haven't been able to try it yet, but will come up with an update by the end of the week. Thank you! @chinmayakamal

Comment: Worked as a charm! Thank you so much!! :) @chinmayakamal